# Find out whether a user has read a post or not

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I have created a ticket system for jobs at work.

There are three tables:

**Job**:
`id|subject|flag|status|deadline|ts`

**Team**:
`id|jobID|userID|vocation`

and **exchange**:
`id|details|foreignID|table|polyflag|userID|ts`

Basically a job is created, *inserted* into `job`, the team is built up and inserted into `team` and any posts and conversation for this particular job is put into `exchange`.

But what I would like to do is find out if a user has not read any posts in a particular job.  Because at the moment, they are having to actually go into the job page, and see if there is anything new in there they havent seen.  If their job list is particularly large, this will become a problem.

So if a user posts something new, and they havent loaded the job and seen it, I want to be able to show them that somehow.  The problem is I have no idea how I can do it.

Suggestions?

Comment: display a list of posts along with a link to the job page (if that helps), then a user can just view a stream of posts without having to view individual jobs (but they have the link there if they want to see the full job record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the answers on here I came up with my own solution, so just for the record, I will put it in here; as none of the other answers really cut it for me.

Okay.  So my aversion from the other answers really stems from the fact that I didnt want to create another table.  I hate clogging up my database with meaningless tables, and I wanted a better solution.

So I modifed the table `team` to:

**Team:** `id|jobID|userID|vocation|exchangeID`

Adding the column `exchangeID`, which basically stores the ID of the latest exchange that this user has read.  This is updated everytime the user views a job.  Easy enough.

Then to find out how many new posts, I simple grab a list from `exchange` of all the IDs relating to that job, and find out where in the list my `team`.`exchangeID` sits and then return the leftover rows gives me unread posts.

I have then stuck this code (20 lines long approx) into a setInterval that loads the data into a  on the job view page, so that now that is automatically updated if anyone posts to a job without the person viewing! Smooth!

Thanks for all your help StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new table with the user_id,job_id columns, and every time someone views a job you insert it there (only for the 1st time), so you can easily select from this table and see which jobs a user viewed or whether a particular job was seen a user

Answer (score 0):

Create another table called readPostStatus with userID, postID and readStatus.

Then on the posts, all statuses will be false for read status. (There are a number of ways to display these results)

Then when a specific user reads the post, edit the readPostStatus table, marking that userID and postID to true in readStatus

Comment: So then, when another user posts into a job, I have to insert X amount of rows (1 for each user) saying they havent seen? then change when they view the post?

Comment: There was never any mention of being able to post into a job, I thought they would just add another job, but never-the-less, yes, just loop through all allowed users and insert their userID, it will be a very simple query and will not have a big load-share because you are just passing ints, so the server will not take strain. Also, a nice idea might be to use ajax or jquery to show the unread/read condition on the post

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are interested in users that are part of the team for a job, rather than users creating the job. Also I guess there is a User table (for which `userID` in `Team` is a foreign key).

What you essentially want is a view counter, for each `User` for each `Job`. This looks like a many to many relationship to me, between the two tables. I would suggest that the best way of doing this is to have another table called `UserJob` or perhaps something more useful, with the fields: `jobID`, `userID`, and `viewCount`. When the job page is loaded you run a query to check whether a record already exists in this table for the job loaded, by the user loading the page. If not then you create it (and initialise the count to 1). Otherwise you increment the view count.

If you don't care about the count, just whether it has been seen or not, then you don't need to bother incrementing the count. You might like to name the field `hasSeen` or something, instead of `viewCount`.

Edit: Forgot to say that you can easily check whether a user has seen a job or not by querying this table, and checking whether a row exists (with `hasSeen` set to 1). Depending on your structure you might want to have the rows of this table automatically added (with `hasSeen` set to 0) when a user is assigned to a job.

Comment: Would there be no fancy way to do it based on timestamps?

Comment: If you're interested in when a user last looked at the job, then you could store a timestamp instead of a view-count (perhaps with NULL to indicate 'never'). This would allow you to calculate whether a user has seen a change in a job that happened at a particular time.